# How can I download historical file from OpenStreetMap?

Tags: maps, openstreetmap, osm.pbf

I need the .pbf file for one country but from last year. Is there any possibility to find it on the OSM ?

Answer (score 3):

Geofabrik keeps older files, one per year. See for example [Europe](https://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html#).

If you need data from a specific date then take a look at the [full history dump](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm/full).

Comment: The trick is to click on "raw directory index".